# How do you conditionally run an Installshield custom action based on a property set by a dialog?

Tags: installshield

I have an installer created with InstallShield 2012. I now have a need to allow the user to optionally run a custom action as part of their uninstall.

To achieve this I have currently added a check box to one of our dialogs. The checkbox is associated with a property and has the default set to 'True' (the 'Value' is set to '1'). In the PropertyManager the property has been added with a Value of '1'.

For the custom action the condition is set to `REMOVE="ALL" AND MyCheckboxProp=1`. When running the installer the checkbox appears initially checked. However, looking in the logs I can see that the condition always evaluates to True even when the checkbox is toggled to the unchecked state.

When the checkbox is unckecked the installer log reports:

```
PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting MyCheckboxProp property. Its current value is '1'.
```

At first I wondered if the issue could relate to the fact that the action was running with 'Deferred Execution'. However, even running a test action with 'Immediate Execution' I can see that the condition always evaluates to 'True'.

As expected from the above, a test action which displays the property value shows it is always 'True'.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept that was missing is that the Windows Installer component which interprets the MSI actually has a notion of [public, private, and restricted public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In this case a property value is being referred to in both the user-interface and the execution phase. The [documentation for public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that:

> Properties that are to be set by the user interface during the
>   installation and then passed to the execution phase of the
>   installation must be public.

To mark a property as public it should be specified such that the name contains only uppercase letters (see [Restrictions on Property Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). In the example given in the question, the property name contains some lower case letters, and as such, was being interpreted as private.

The additional benefit of marking a property as public is that it allows the property to be [set on the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it can then be specified when performing a silent install.

Comment: Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370912(v=vs.85).aspx

The property won't cross from client context to server context if it isn't ALL CAPS, unless you add it to the SecureCustomProperties.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the link it makes things much clearer. I'll try and update the answer to reflect some of that.

Comment: You also want the property to be be a secure public property so that it can be passed at the cmdline in a silent installation scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated the answer to make it clearer but please feel free to edit it if there's anything I've missed.